# Project is not listed in coverity portal

Tags: coverity-prevent, coverity

I created one new project in coverity and I am able to commits defects in that project.  When I open the coverity portal my project is not listed but it is listed in the configuration window.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to refresh the CIM window after doing a commit for it to show up.

Are you logging in as the same user as when you commit your defects?

Comment: I logging in as the same user name which i used for commit command

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to get the snapshot ID after a successful commit into the project into the coverity integrity manager ? It displays the snapshot ID once the commit data is imported.